# What is the best way to add more disk space on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

At the moment I have one boot disk with size of 10 GB. For what I see google it cost me $1.70 per / month , which mean it's a type "SSD provisioned space"  ( $0.170 per GB/Month).

I want to use type "Standard provisioned space" which is $0.040 per GB/Month . 
i.e  for 100 GB the price is $4  vs  $17

Is it possible to set boot disk to be "Standard provisioned space" and resize it to 100 GB , or I need to add new disk from type "Standard provisioned space" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to create a new disk. 
You can migrate the content of the current disk to the new disk following the next steps.

- Create snapshot of the persistent disk.
- Create a new standard disk from the snapshot.

At this point you have two choices:

- Create a new instance with the SSD disk as a boot disk, unassign the static IP from old instance and attach it to the new instance. Once done delete the old instance. This will have has less or almost no downtime.
- Delete the old instance, create a new instance with the new disk and assign the static IP. This will reduce the cost but will have downtime.

(Source: [Change Google Compute/Cloud Server to SSD Persistent Disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994615/change-google-compute-cloud-server-to-ssd-persistent-disk))

Comment: To add to Eduardo's answer, you can detach the current boot disk and attach the new disk that you created to your instance. You must use the CLI for this. `gcloud compute instance detach-disk NAME --disk=DISK --zone=ZONE` and `gcloud beta compute instances attach-disk NAME --disk=DISK --zone=ZONE --boot`